# How to open Non-Default Outlook Calendar from MS Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I want the users of a form in MS Access to be able to access a shared calendar(only read) in Outlook. So basically:

MS Acess > Opens Users Outlook > Shows "Shared calendar"(which is located on the company's MS Exchange server)

Platform: Windows 7x64, Office2013 x32

I had no problems accessing the default calendar but that's about it. I have tried a couple of things like hard coding a direct path to the calendar like "my.email@domain.com\My Calendars\Shared calendar but that didn't help...

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Dim olkApp, olkSes, olkFolder
On Error Resume Next
Set olkApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If TypeName(olkApp) <> "Application" Then
    Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olkSes = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Change Outlook on the next line to the name of the default mail profile'
    olkSes.Logon "Outlook"
Else
    Set olkSes = olkApp.Session
End If

'Set olkFolder = olkSes.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
'Instead of just accessing the default calendar like the code above does
'I tried a direct path(code below) which does not work...

Set olkFolder = GetFolderPath(olkApp, "my.email@domain.com\MyCalendars\Shared Calendar")
olkFolder.Display
Set olkApp = Nothing
Set olkSes = Nothing
Set olkFolder = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: To see the path use the Folders view not the Calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a WebCal calendar, use [NameSpace.OpenSharedFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.opensharedfolder). If the owner gave the user delegate access to their calendar, use [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder).

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder instead of GetFolderPath?

Comment: Yes, GetSharedDefaultFolder returns a Folder object while GetFolderPath returns a string of the folder path

Comment: Tried that but no luck.

Comment: No luck how? Error?